# Custom application page

Tags: 2010, master-page

I am confused with complicated question, I am not understanding what they are asking in questoin, and what answer is doing,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default (particularly in 2007) Application pages we're not inheriting the master page dynamically as regular pages. In SharePoint 2010, you could use dynamic tokens (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537530(v=office.14).aspx) to load whatever the site has configured or you could override that by setting, in design-time the MasterPageFile to be used by the application page (physically stored in Layouts folder and exposed via the Virtual directory _layouts). To my knowledge the MasterPageFile is mainly in SharePoint Foundation used, where as in SharePoint server it is recomanded to use the DynamicToken